# Change the LDAP settings on a WAS from outside of the GUI

Tags: ldap, ibm

I have a virtual image of a WAS server but it can no longer access the LDAP/AD that holds the administration password as it has moved to a different network. As a result, I can't login to change the settings.

I want to change the IP of the address by hand or turn off security so that I can login and change it by hand.

I knew a way to do this once...

Answer (score 1):

To disable administrative security navigate to the **$WAS_PROFILE/bin** directory and issue,

```
wsadmin -conntype NONE
```

Enter the following in the wsadmin prompt,

```
securityoff
quit
```

Restart the WAS server.

*Administrative security can be re-enabled via the console. Click through **Security > Global Security** and select the **Enable administrative security** check box. Restart the WAS server.